# What is the best way to alias method names in python?

Tags: python, design-patterns

Hi I've written the following code:

```
class Car:
  def __init__(self):
    self._create_aliases()

  def take_to_repair_shop(self):
     pass

  def drive_to_the_beach(self):
     pass

  def _create_aliases(self):
     Car.repair = Car.take_to_repair_shop
     Car.beach = Car.drive_to_the_beach
```

I want the user to have the option of using the longer, clearer names, or the shorter names. 
I made `_create_aliases` into an instance method so that it could be overriden.

Are there any problems with this? Is this a good design pattern?

Comment: In Python, avoid non-functional aliases. You are increasing the complexity of the interface for no good reason. "There should be one -- and preferably only one -- obvious way to do it."

Comment: how do you define non-functional?

Comment: there are cases when you might need it e.g., `next` as an alias for `__next__` could be used to support the iterator protocol in both Python 2 and 3 from the same source.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't need to do it in `__init__`:

```
class Car:

    def take_to_repair_shop(self):
        pass

    def drive_to_the_beach(self):
        pass

    repair = take_to_repair_shop # <---
    beach = drive_to_the_beach   # <---
```

Example:

```
>>> car = Car()
>>> car.repair()
>>> car.take_to_repair_shop()
>>>
```

Comment: oh right, I guess a subclass  could always change or remove the aliases without overriding anything. thanks

Comment: @user553965 No. You cannot delete something inherited without overriding (shadowing) it.

Comment: You can later do: `del Car.repair`, or in a subclass: `repair=None` to get rid of the alias

Comment: @user553965, Deleting using `del Car.repair` will break codes that use `repair` method.

Comment: What if a subclass wants to overwrite the method? They'd have to know which one is the real one.

Comment: This works perfectly, but what if the method to alias is inherited (e. g., `class A(): def a(self)`, `class B(A): b = a`, throwing a `NameError`; Python 2.7)?