# How to alias a Python constructor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, alias

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264923/define-method-aliases-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21072711/what-is-the-best-way-to-alias-method-names-in-python) that Python methods can be aliased using `=`.

However, when I try it on the `__init__` method, it doesn't seem to work.

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Hi mum!")
    
    new_name = __init__

a = MyClass()
b = MyClass.new_name()
```

The `b = MyClass.new_name()` causes this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Why does this not work? And how should I alias `__init__` correctly?

Comment: Make `new_name` static or class method that returns new `MyClass` object.

Comment: @AndrejKesely Yeah, that was also my first idea for a workaround. But I would still like to understand why my code above doesn't work.

Comment: The `__init__` method expects the positional argument `self`, as you can see by it's definition. When you call the `new_name` method explicitly from the class, there is no positional argument passed, like there is implicitly when instantiating a new object

Comment: @schwartz721 Can I mimic this implicit behavior somehow? Making `new_name` a static method seems inconvenient because if the parameters of `__init__` change, then I also have to update the parameters of `new_name`, and the arguments to `MyClass(...)` inside `new_name`.

Comment: You can call the `__new__` method of a class to create an instance without it automatically calling the `__init__` method. So you could do something like `b = MyClass.new_name(MyClass.__new__(MyClass))`. You'll have to modify the `__init__` method to return `self` though, so that `b` points to the instance created

Comment: Basically, calling `__new__` first gives you the reference to the instance of the class that you need to call `new_name`

Comment: `__init__` is an instance method and you should call with an instance name, say `b = a.new_name()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__init__` is not a constructor. `__new__` is. `__init__` is an instance method that performs initialization on an instance after it is constructed by the static method `__new__`. The reason why both `__new__` and `__init__` are called when you call the class with `MyClass()` is because it is what the `__call__` method of the type, or metaclass, of `MyClass`, does.

So if you want to properly alias the constructor of a class you can alias the `__call__` method of its metaclass:

```
class AliasedConstructor(type):
    new_name = type.__call__

class MyClass(metaclass=AliasedConstructor):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Hi mum!")

MyClass.new_name()
```

Alternatively, you can make the alias a `classmethod` descriptor that binds `type.__call__` to the current class:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Hi mum!")

    new_name = classmethod(type.__call__)
```

Both approaches would output:

```
Hi mum!
```

Comment: Introducing a meta lass for this seems like overkill

Comment: Indeed the use of a metaclass was more of a demonstration of what happens when you call `MyClass()`, that the `__call__` method of the metaclass is called. I've updated my answer to do away from a metaclass. +1 to your answer too.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if my answer actually works. On the Metro right now...

Comment: It does work, though it feels weird indeed to modify a class after its definition.

Answer (score 1):

The `__init__` method was aliased. But `__init__` is not a constructor to begin with.

You could probably do:

```
MyClass.new_name = MyClass.__call__
```

If you want things to "just work".

This is assuming your class doesn't define a `__call__` method that would shadow `type.__call__`.

But this is rather weird to begin with, IMO. Just define a `classmethod`.